# DIfferent forms, same dialog box

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a dilemma and I guess the best way to solve it is to turn to the community. I have an Add button, that gives you a list of options. Depending on which option you choose it should show a dialog box and a form.

What is the best way to do it?

1. Have all the forms already coded and delivered and activate the right one (**this might mean that I have to repeat a lot of code and it's not an optimized way of doing things**)
2. Load the form through Ajax (**this could be a good way if it wouldn't come with the expense of having to fetch the form from the server**)
3. Create it dynamically in Javascript? (**the best?**)

Answer (score 2):

First one is surely not an option if you have most of the questions same.

Option 2 and 3 have both their plus/minus points.

- **AJAX Fetching Form**

  This way, you avoid cluster on the code page, you can hide certain options from users until they select particular option (this can be both good/bad depending on circustances).

  Might involve more time in fetching data from another server, but less processing on client side, more on server side.
- **Dynamic Javascript**

  Quite opposite of the above, all the form generating rules will have to be in form of JS and thus available in source code. Can cluster it a bit, and not hidden.

  More data processing on client side than on server side.

If it was upto me, I would do AJAX one, just because it looks cleaner, but depending on your restrictions/tolerance, you may go for 3 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Second option is same with the first one; to fetch the right form, you must have forms already there.

Third option is good but it is not so edit-friendly. You will come to your code after 3 weeks and BOM!

I can recommend you to AJAX one, even if you write that much of code. [But pay attention to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043693/jquery-ajax-cutting-off-response-in-ie/11099137#11099137)

Comment: Not necessarily. You might have background scripts (say php) generating the form on server and then sending them back to the page.